# Query Failure when Joining queries with LTRIM in SAP BW Eclipse Console

Tags: sql, eclipse, hana, opensql, sap-bw

I am trying to run a simple query in Eclipse based SQL Console in BW/4HANA environment but the query fails with the following error:

> "(" is not allowed here. "." is expected.

Query is as follows:

```
  SELECT A2~BBP_PO_ID, A2~BBP_POITEM, A3~OI_EBELP, A3~DSDEL_DATE
  FROM /BIC/AXXX2 as A2 
  INNER JOIN /BIC/AYYY2 AS A3
        ON A2~BBP_PO_ID = A3~OI_EBELN 
        AND LTRIM( A2~OI_EBELP,'0' ) =  
                LTRIM( A3~BBP_POITEM,'0' )
```

A3~BBP_POITEM is a CHAR(5) and A2~OI_EBELP is a CHAR(10).

Note that issue only happens when LTRIM is being used in my join condition, otherwise I am able to project the column trimmed of 0's via my SELECT successfully.

It is also not clear to me as to what standards "SQL Console" follows. Does it follow "Open SQL" grammar/rules or "HANA SQL" grammar/rules.

Any feedback or guidance is appreciated.

TIA!

Tried a simple join SQL but continues to fail with error quoted in my post.
I also tried the same SQL within the ADT in Eclipse and even with the ABAP code the statement fails with same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use HANA SQL languague.
for example SELECT LTRIM ('babababAabend','ab') "ltrim" FROM DUMMY;
please feedback to me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34635170)